# Getting Avalilable lookup columns in Loookup transformation into Lookup not match output path in ssis?

Tags: ssis, dataflowtask

Can anyone suggest how to get Available lookup columns in Loookup transformation into Lookup No match ouput path?

please suggest me any way how can I get those columns in Available lookup columns into Lookup No match ouput path?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can - perhaps use a derived column transform before the lookup to add the lookup columns then do a "replace" on the lookup MATCHES to replace the columns where there is data.

The no Match output will then have the columns as they are already in the data flow.

Hope this makes sense....